# Finding the value of $x+y+z$ given sums of two and square root of the other

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, systems-of-equations

Given: $$x+y+\sqrt{z}=148$$
$$x+\sqrt{y}+z=82$$
$$\sqrt{x}+y+z=98$$

Find the value of $x+y+z$ such that x, y, and z are positive integers.

The only significant step I did was to let $a^2=x, b^2=y, c^2=z.$ After that, I just played with the equations, adding and subtracting, letting $S=x+y+z$, finding equations for S. But I always come to a dead end. Can anyone show me the solution?

Comment: The set of $x, y, z$ need only test perfect squares  $(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144)$. Doing an exhaustive search gives $(x, y, z) = (64, 81, 9)$.

Comment: So is it basically just trial and error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from your step, we subtract the second equation from the third. We then have
$$a-a^2 +b^2-b =16$$ 
or
$$(b-a)(b+a-1)=16$$
No the possible combinations are: $\{1,16\}$, $\{2,8\}$, or $\{4,4\}$. A quick check tells you only the first will work. Thus $b-a=1$ and $b+a-1= 16$. From this we get $a=8$ and $b=9$. Subtracting the third equation from the first we have 
$$
a^2-a + c -c^2=50$$ from which we can solve for $c$ and we obtain $c(c-1)=6$ or $c=3$. Thus $x=64, y =81, z =9.$

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Honestly, I already reached the equation $(b-a)(b+a-1)=16$ but unfortunately I thought that this was a dead end since I saw that many possibilities may arise; such as, the ones you have given, their inverses, their negatives and the inverses of their negatives. My questions are: how did you know that you should disregard {16,1}, {-1,-16}, etc.? Also, what do you mean by "a quick check"?

Comment: I actually didn't consider negative values. Because of this $b-a$ was smaller than $b+a-1$ and so I only had to look an the pairs where the first was smaller than the second. It is something worth looking at though.

Comment: When I tried the other pairs it was clear that the answers were not an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I had a look at the negatives again just to be clear with this. It is implicit that $a, b, c$ are all positive so we only have to look at $b-a$ and $b+a-1$. If $b-a$ is negative then $b+a-1$ must also be negative which cannot happen for positive $b, a$.

Comment: @Carl - In the equation $(b-a)(b+a-1)=16$ one factor on the lhs must be odd and one must be even, so to have an even product, the odd factor must equal 1. Because we already know that $b>a$ we have that $b=a+1$. From this follows what user110502 has derived

Answer (score 0):

$$x + y + \sqrt{z} = 148$$ $$x + \sqrt{y} + z = 82$$ $$\sqrt{x} + y + z = 98$$
As $x, y , z$ are positive integers and each of the sum is positive integer, that means $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt{y}$, $\sqrt{z}$ are also integers.

So, that means $x, y, z$ are perfect squares less than $148$.

Thus, x, y, z can be one of the following {$1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144$}.

If we see the 3 equation, it is clear that, the max possible value of $x = 64,$ $y = 81$ and $z = 16$.

Now, by hit n trail method, it can be determined within 2-3 guesses that the only possible solution will be as follows - $$ x = 64, y = 81, z = 9$$

So, the final answer is, $$x + y + z = 154$$